# Virtual Memory Usage Exceeding Physical Drive Space

Tags: memory, top, htop

I have a machine running Ubuntu on Amazon EC2. The machine has a 43 Gb root drive and 30 Gb of RAM. I am running a processor and memory intensive process and I've noticed that it sometimes stalls for no apparent reason. 
I'm looking at the system usage via the `htop` program. I've included a screenshot below.

Does it make sense that the VIRT column adds up to more than the physical drive space of the system? My understanding is that is virtual memory usage. Essentially I'm trying to understand whether my process is freezing because it's running out of resources, and which resources it's running out of.

[image: System usage. Virtual memory is exceeding the root drive space.]

Comment: `RSS` is the physical memory used, `VIRT` is the entire address space (swap+RSS)

Comment: `RSS`, do you mean `RES`? The sum of the `RES` column exceeds the total memory the system has - 30gb

Comment: Yeah `RSS` is the same as `RES`. Since the `VIRT` and `RES` for several of those processes match up, I'd see if those PID's are threads of the same process, in which case they'll share the same memory and so should only be counted once.

Comment: The processes I'm talking about are the 10.1GB for VIRT and 9121MB for RSS.

Comment: I'm assuming you checked and they are? If you aren't sure, you can try going go into `setup>display options` and tell it to display threads in a different color.

Comment: Well since you appear to have gone MIA, I'll just say I did the math and if you count those probably-threads only once you get just shy of 29GB. Once you factor in filesystem cache and processes we're not seeing up there, that's pretty close to your 30GB.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The process finished (in this case) so I can't actively verify. The color coding will help. I didn't realize that threads in the same processes would show up separately but share resources.

Comment: The sum of virts is not the total vert. There is overlap, shared libraries show up multiple times, also multiple instances of the same executable, or any forked process.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal; it's because Linux has overcommit (`overcommit.ratio`) and VIRT is also shared memory between processes that use the same shared objects.